# Storing certain file line values in different lists

Tags: python, data-science

I have a file where each line represents user, item, rating and timestamp, where the list is sorted from 0th user to nth user then by least recently timestamped entry to most recent as shown here:

```
0,1,5,1412899200
0,1,5,1412899200
0,6,5,1412899200
1,12,5,1458432000
1,12,5,1458432000
1,17,5,1458432000
```

I want to store each user's most recent timestamped entry in a test list, 2nd most recent in a validation list and the rest in a train list. My first idea is storing each user's entries as an object in a list and splitting by comparing index values. But I'm just wondering, is there a better/more efficient way I can achieve this?
Edit: Here's my current code (sortedSamples is the file containing all entries):

```py
train = []
validation = []
test = []
userEntries = []
with open("sortedSamples", 'r') as y:
    data = y.readlines()
    idx = 0
    for line in data:
        nMin = 0
        entry = [int(x) for x in line.split(",")]
        user = entry[0]
        if user == idx:
            userEntries.append(entry)
        else:
            idx += 1
            for entry in range(len(userEntries)):
                if entry == 0:
                    min = userEntries[entry][3]
                    test.append(userEntries[entry])
                else:
                    if nMin == 0 and nMin != min:
                        nMin = userEntries[entry][3]
                        validation.append(userEntries[entry])
                    else:
                        if userEntries[entry][3] == min:
                            test.append(userEntries[entry])
                        elif userEntries[entry][3] == nMin:
                            validation.append(userEntries[entry])
                        else:
                            train.append(userEntries[entry])
            userEntries = []
return train, validation, test
```